# Ignoring plotting None values

Tags: python

There is an array [4,1, None, 2, None, 6].
Is it possible to make a matplotlib plot with evenly spaced values, in this case, 6 values in such a way that the number values are plotted and None values are empty such that there is twice such a long space between 1 and 2 and it is between 4 and 1.

Comment: What happened when you tried assuming there is no problem and just providing the data to Matplotlib as is?

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` does this for you automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [4,1, None, 2, None, 6]
plt.plot(x,'.')
plt.show()
```

[image]